# UPNP Curl SetVolume fails with <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode> errorCode -111

Tags: curl, soap, upnp

I am currently trying to play a sound file over wifi to a iDeaUSA w205 box.
So far everything works except for the volume setting and I just don´t get the point.

initiating: working

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetAVTransportURI"' -d '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:SetAVTransportURI
            xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
            <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
            <CurrentURI>
                <![CDATA[http://192.168.178.46/naturesounds.ogg]]>
            </CurrentURI>
            <CurrentURIMetaData></CurrentURIMetaData>
        </u:SetAVTransportURI>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
' 'http://192.168.178.61:49152/upnp/control/rendertransport1'
```

playing: working

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Play"' -d '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:Play
            xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
            <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
            <Speed>1</Speed>
        </u:Play>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>  
' 'http://192.168.178.61:49152/upnp/control/rendertransport1'
```

SetVolume: not working

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetVolume"' -d '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <u:SetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
         <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
         <Channel>Master</Channel>
         <DesiredVolume>12</DesiredVolume>
      </u:SetVolume>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
' 'http://192.168.178.61:49152/upnp/control/rendertransport1'
```

I just don´t get the point, the curious thing is it is working with the **Device Spy** from **Developer Tools for UPNP**

This is the error I get in return, whatever errorcode -111 is, I have no idea.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
<detail>
<UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
<errorCode>-111</errorCode>
<errorDescription>Invalid Action</errorDescription>
</UPnPError>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here the sniffed stuff from the Spytool including the return, which works there:

```
POST /upnp/control/rendercontrol1 HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.178.61:49152
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetVolume"
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 424

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <u:SetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
         <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
         <Channel>Master</Channel>
         <DesiredVolume>12</DesiredVolume>
      </u:SetVolume>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CONTENT-LENGTH: 259
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
DATE: Sun, 30 Oct 2016 15:54:42 GMT
EXT:
SERVER: Linux/2.6.21, UPnP/1.0, Portable SDK for UPnP devices/1.6.17

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body>
<u:SetVolumeResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"></u:SetVolumeResponse>
</s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

Am I blind? Where is the difference, I just don´t see it. I think 111 is some connection refused in curl however that doesn´t explain why it is working from the tool and not from my raspberry pi (where I actually run the curl script) nor might a firewall issue be the problem because the first two curls do work.

**EDIT : solution: it is rendercontrol1 not rendertransport1 for the volume**

correct for volume, for everybody interested in this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetVolume"' -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><u:SetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel><DesiredVolume>12</DesiredVolume></u:SetVolume></s:Body></s:Envelope>' 'http://192.168.178.61:49152/upnp/control/rendercontrol1'
```

Apart from that this device loves to call some chinese sites for DNS. So much for iDea"USA" ;-) so you may wanna block it from calling home in your router.

Comment: -111 is not a valid UPnP or HTTP error code ( it's probably a bug in the server) but the message is clear: "Invalid Action". Have you checked that the Service supports `SetVolume()` as it's not a required feature?

Comment: Yes the error message is a little weird but I assume it should be 111 instead of -111. SetVolume is a supported feature, I took a look at the specific XML sheets and the Device Spy is able to use it, as mentioned above. It is a bit funny though that "Play" works through AVTransport but actually isn´t an action there. However SetVolume doesn´t work there and it isn´t listed there as action so I just tried as Device Spy does with RenderingControl, just without luck. Curl is the latest version on the raspberry pi so that shouldn´t be the problem either.

Comment: 111 is not a valid error either afaik.  401 is Invalid Action and 512-401=111: my guess is that server does a broken unsigned to signed  conversion.

Comment: My suggestion is to use wireshark and compare the actual messages on the wire: obviously there is a difference in what you send and what your device spy is sending

Comment: As I guessed wireshark isn´t helping much here because the Device Spy already sniffs the traffic. However I did with wireshark to doublecheck and it does exactly the same:  (cut too long here)

Comment: I still maintain the messages very likely are somehow different.  Can you post the sniffed message from both?

Comment: just found the issue, see above. As I expected I was blind :-/  - so wireshark was indeed a good idea because the device spy doesn´t spit out that curl part